# Creating react pages with unique urls

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a route with a url that changes based on the id of the object I clicked to access the route.

```
//Route
<Route path="InColl/:id" component={InColl}/>

//InColl Component
import React from 'react'
import './css/InColl.css';

export default function InColl({match}) {
    const userId = match.params.id;
    return (
        <div className="margin">
            <div className="inv">
               Hello World!!!
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The :id changes via the link component underneath. I mapped an array of objects each with their own unique id. Depending on which object I click, I will be taken to a new page with the url looking like "
http://localhost:3000/InColl/(The Id of The Object)".

```
<Link to={"InColl/" + this.props.c._id} >
```

For some reason the InColl page with the unique id doesn't render anything. I'm not sure what the issue is and I would appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: can you share your router with all the routes please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/The routes need to be a relative path

change route to

```
<Route path="/InColl/:id" component={InColl}/>
```

and link to

```
<Link to={"/InColl/" + this.props.c._id} >
```